# Loop Through Charts on Selected (or Range of) Powerpoint Slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2013

I am currently using this code to update all links in my powerpoint presentation:

```
Sub UpdateLinks()
Dim ExcelFile
Dim exl As Object
Set exl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

ExcelFile = "C:\Users\J\Documents\Reporting\Governance Physical Charts.xlsm"

Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Integer

 'Go through every slide
For i = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
    With ActivePresentation.Slides(i)
         'Go through every shape on every slide
        For k = 1 To .Shapes.Count
On Error Resume Next
             'Set the source to be the same as teh file chosen in the opening dialog box
            .Shapes(k).LinkFormat.SourceFullName = ExcelFile
            If .Shapes(k).LinkFormat.SourceFullName = ExcelFile Then
                 'If the change was successful then also set it to update automatically
                .Shapes(k).LinkFormat.AutoUpdate = ppUpdateOptionAutomatic 'other option is ppUpdateOptionManual
            End If

        Next k
    End With
Next i
End Sub
```

Instead of updating the link of every chart in the presentation, is it possible to have this code loop through only selected slides?  Or if it's easier - is it possible to set a range?  For example, only update charts on slides 15-30?

Thank you!

EDIT:
Resolution provided in comments - here is my revised code

```
Sub UpdateLinks()
Dim ExcelFile
Dim exl As Object
Set exl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim sld As Slide

ExcelFile = "C:\Users\J\Documents\Reporting\Governance Physical Charts.xlsm"

Dim i As Integer
Dim shp As Shape

 For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(Array(11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18))

        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
On Error Resume Next
            shp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = ExcelFile
            If shp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = ExcelFile Then
                shp.LinkFormat.AutoUpdate = ppUpdateOptionAutomatic 'other option is ppUpdateOptionManual
            End If

        Next shp


Next
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you *can* compose custom ranges on `Slides` as well as on `Shapes`, using an `Array` as the `index` parameter. Try this:

```
Dim sld As Slide
For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(Array(1, 3, 5))
    Debug.Print sld.Name
Next
```

Output:

> Slide2
>   Slide4
>   Slide6

p.s. I had deleted a slide in the test presentation.

Comment: Thank you @A.S.H - this worked!  Posting my revised code in edit

Comment: @jennaisavol would you please mark the question as answered (clicking the checkmark on the topleft of the answer)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you also mentioned processing just selected slides, you can do that like so:

```
Sub SelectedSlides()
    Dim osl As Slide
    For Each osl In ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange
        Debug.Print osl.SlideIndex
    Next
End Sub
```

Note that this will give you the selected slides in REVERSE order of selection. That is, if you control-click slides 2,4,6, this will give you 6,4,2.