# Animation removal from activated slide only

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to remove animation with the help of vbscript in powerpoint.
But it should remove only from selected slide not from all slides

I have tried some code but it's removing from all the slides sharing below the sample code, can anyone please help me with the solution

```
Sub RemoveAllAnimations()
'PURPOSE: Remove All PowerPoint Animations From Slides
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault

Dim sld As Slide
Dim x As Long
Dim Counter As Long

'Loop Through Each Slide in ActivePresentation
  For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides

'Loop through each animation on slide
  For x = sld.TimeLine.MainSequence.Count To 1 Step -1

    'Remove Each Animation
      sld.TimeLine.MainSequence.Item(x).Delete

    'Maintain Deletion Stat
      Counter = Counter + 1

  Next x

  Next sld

'Completion Notification
MsgBox Counter & " Animation(s) were removed from you PowerPoint presentation!"

End Sub
```

Its removing animation from all the slides

Comment: Your first For Loop is going through each slide. This is clearly stated in the ***purpose*** comment someone wrote from wherever you pulled the code from. You may need to write more code or alter the existing code to downselect to which slide you wish to remove the animations from.

Comment: The code you posted is not VBScript but likely as you are using it in Powerpoint it’s VBA (Visual Basic for Applications).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For just the selected slide:

```
Sub RemoveAllAnimations()
  Dim sld As Slide
  Dim x As Long
  Dim Counter As Long

  Set sld = ActiveWindow.View.Slide
  For x = sld.TimeLine.MainSequence.Count To 1 Step -1
    sld.TimeLine.MainSequence.Item(x).Delete
    Counter = Counter + 1
  Next x
  Set sld = Nothing
  MsgBox Counter & " Animation(s) were removed from your PowerPoint presentation!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks John Korchok, it worked for me, is there any other code for remove animations from selected slides.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: This answer should help you   [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42096091/loop-through-charts-on-selected-or-range-of-powerpoint-slides)